# textbox multiline delete all rows starting with a certain character

Tags: .net, vb.net

I'd like to delete in a textbox multiline, all rows that starts with a char different from 1-9 numbers, in other terms, I'd like to delete all rows starting with a-z A-Z and 0. I made several tests thinking it was easy, but I didn't solved yet.
It seems that's not so easy to handle a textbox multiline normally.
This is the last code that I tried without success.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    Dim lines() As String
    lines = TextBox1.Lines

    For Each line As String In lines
        If line.Length >= 1 Then
            Dim firstLetter As Char
            firstLetter = line.Substring(0, 1)

            If firstLetter = "S" Then
                TextBox1.Lines.ToArray
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: How about showing your code? Where do you run into troubles? Where does your code not work as expected?

Comment: @Shrotter Right, I added it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of variations but the simplest and most succinct is to use LINQ:

```vb
Dim lines = From line In TextBox1.Lines
            Let firstChar = line(0)
            Where Char.IsDigit(firstChar) AndAlso firstChar <> "0"c
            Select line

TextBox1.Lines = lines.ToArray()
```

Firstly, this code assumes that every line contains at least one character. If that's not the case then you'd have to make the appropriate adjustment.

The `Let` keyword allows you to create a local variable within a LINQ query, which is handy here because it allows us to use the same value multiple times without using a complex expression to get that value multiple times.

The filter first gets the lines that start with a digit, then excludes the ones that start with a '0'.

Alternatively, you can use a conventional loop:

```vb
Dim lines = TextBox1.Lines.ToList()

For i = lines.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
    Dim firstChar = lines(i)(0)

    If firstChar = "0"c OrElse Not Char.IsDigit(firstChar) Then
        lines.RemoveAt(i)
    End If
Next

TextBox1.Lines = lines.ToArray()
```

You need to create a collection from the `Lines` array, so you can remove items. As is always the case, if you want to modify the collection as you loop, you need to loop backwards, so changes don't affect the index of items yet to be processed.

If you might have blank lines and you want to exclude them as well, these will work:

```vb
Dim lines = From line In TextBox1.Lines
            Let firstChar = line.FirstOrDefault()
            Where Char.IsDigit(firstChar) AndAlso firstChar <> "0"c
            Select line

TextBox1.Lines = lines.ToArray()
```

```vb
Dim lines = TextBox1.Lines.ToList()

For i = lines.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
    Dim firstChar = lines(i).FirstOrDefault()

    If firstChar = "0"c OrElse Not Char.IsDigit(firstChar) Then
        lines.RemoveAt(i)
    End If
Next

TextBox1.Lines = lines.ToArray()
```

If you want to retain blank lines:

```vb
Dim lines = From line In TextBox1.Lines
            Let firstChar = line.FirstOrDefault()
            Where firstChar = ControlChars.NullChar OrElse (Char.IsDigit(firstChar) AndAlso firstChar <> "0"c)
            Select line

TextBox1.Lines = lines.ToArray()
```

```vb
Dim lines = TextBox1.Lines.ToList()

For i = lines.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
    Dim firstChar = lines(i).FirstOrDefault()

    If firstChar = "0"c OrElse (firstChar <> ControlChars.NullChar AndAlso Not Char.IsDigit(firstChar)) Then
        lines.RemoveAt(i)
    End If
Next

TextBox1.Lines = lines.ToArray()
```

Comment: I tried this snippet also but it detect 2 errors, one on "AndAlso" as wrong sintax, and one on the last line. Cannot convert value of type '<anonymous type: Key line As String, Key firstChar As Char> ()' to 'String ()' because '<anonymous type: Key line As String, Key firstChar As Char>' does not is derived from 'String'.

Comment: @AlexPad, sorry, I typed that code in directly rather than copying from VS. I have addressed those errors.

Comment: @AlexPad, I have also added a non-LINQ option.

Comment: I tried also the second option but I get error "System.IndexOutOfRangeException" at "Dim firstChar = lines(i)(0)". I also tried to edit my code replacing "TextBox1.Lines.ToArray" with "TextBox1.Lines.ToList().RemoveAt(line)" and with "TextBox1.Lines.ToList().RemoveAt(count)" with in both cases it didn't work.

Comment: The changes you made are bad. The Lines property doesn't work that way. It's not a live list of the lines in the control. It returns a new array every time you get it, so changing that array has no effect on the control. That's why you have assign back to the property at the end. You should know this because you should have read the documentation.

Comment: As for the index issue, I tested that code and it worked for me. You should do the outlet debugging to work out which index is the issue. If it's the second one then that means that you must have a line with no characters and I already addressed that.

Comment: @AlexPad, I have added code examples that can handle blank lines.

Comment: I see 2 couples of snippets, I don't know what does the second but anyway the first one of both seems to work very well, thanks!

Comment: @AlexPad, please accept the answer if it solves your issue, so everyone can see that you need no more help without opening the question. As for what does what, just read what I wrote in the answer.